# How do I use HTML & PHP forms to insert data into a database?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, forms

So I am actually not sure what I am doing wrong, and I am sure it is just some small mistake, but I can't seem to get the submit button to take the information in the form and and send it to the database.

Here is what my code looks like.

So with this I am able to successfully connect to the database:

```
<?php

$mysql_host = 'localhost';
$mysql_pass = '';
$mysql_user = 'root';``

$mysql_db = 'blog';

if (! @mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) || ! @mysql_select_db($mysql_db)){
die('Error');
}

?>
```

and I able to see the contents of table by printing them to the screen.

I believe the problem is here in this simple html form:

```
            <form action="index.php" method = "post">


            <div class="ui form">
                <div class="field" name = "title">
               <label>Title</label>
                <input type="text">
            </div>
              <div class="field" name = "post">
                <label>New Post</label>
                <textarea></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="ui submit button" name = "submit">Submit New Post</div>


        </form>
```

I am just curious as to which php code I should use to connect this form so I am able to send the contents of the form over to the database.

Comment: You need to define the `name` attribute for the values to be posted from the form and used in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `name` attribute from the input fields , and the `submit` should be a input if you are a using normal `PHP` form submit

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

and change the submit div to a input

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit New Post" />
```

Answer (score 6):

elements can be styled just like  elements and can have type="submit" so the instead of div you can use and avoid extra spaces between attributes and values. Instead of your code:

```
<div class="ui submit button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit New Post</div>
```

you can use:

```
<button class="ui submit button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit New Post</button>
```

as like :

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <div class="ui form">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label>New Post</label>
            <textarea type="text"  name="post"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="ui submit button" type="submit" name="submit">Submit New Post</button>
</form>
```

I hope you will get your desire result.

Answer (score 2):

provide the name field into the html tags e.g.

```
    <form  action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <input type="text" name="Sub-title">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Inside index.php you can write

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
$subtitle = $_POST['Sub-title'];
```

Answer (score 2):

You missing name attribute from the fields and elements can be styled just like elements and can have type="submit" so the instead of div you can use and avoid extra spaces between attributes and values.

and change input of a submit div

Submit New Post

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `name` attribute in your form fields:

```
<input type="text">
```

Should be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="title">
```

This is mandatory in order to be able to retrieve your `POST` datas in your PHP page, and it applies to every input you need to process in your PHP page (in this case your `<input>` and your `<textarea>` elements).

Once done this, you'll be able to retrieve each specific `POST` value in your PHP page by accessing the superglobal array `$_POST`:

```
$title = $_POST['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
<div class="ui submit button" name = "submit">Submit New Post</div>
```

it should be:

```
<div class="ui submit button" type="submit" name = "submit">Submit New Post</div>
```

However, I suggest you use PDo to handle this for better.